# Print original text for all JSON leaf primitives

Tags: json

Is there a simple way to iterate through a JSON object/array that contains children nested arbitrarily deeply and print out the original text used for all leaf primitives, including names within objects as leaves?  For example this input:

```
{"foo":"bar",[1.000,1.0,"\u002f","/",null]}
```

Would produce this output:

```
"foo"
"bar"
1.000
1.0
"\u002f"
"/"
null
```

I am interested in the original text as opposed to a normalized value after parsing.  In the above example, my concern is that 1.000 and 1.0 would be stored and reported as the same after parsing for most parsers, as would "\u002f" and "/".

Any tool that would facilitate this would be fine.  It doesn't need to be a particular language.

Comment: maybe interesting? [Streaming big json files the good way with php](http://soyuka.me/streaming-big-json-files-the-good-way/). It should return you the original symbols?